# Android custom ListView with ImageButton is not getting focus

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, imagebutton

I am developing an app for android TV. I have a `listview` with an `ImageButton` + `Textview`s as children. As TV does not take touch events but uses D-PAD or trackball remote I have to get focus on all clickable items so that user knows where the focus is. But the problem is I can get focus on list row if I add

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

in the custom list row layout but `ImageButton` in the list row will not get focus. 
And if I remove above code then `ImageButton` gets focus but I can't click list row.

Also I added [`setItemsCanFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setItemsCanFocus%28boolean%29) for my `ListView` but no luck, nothing changed.
I read many documents but i could not find a proper answer for this problem. I want focus on both List row as well as `ImageButton`. Is it possible, if any one knows please help me...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I have to get focus on all clickable items so that user knows where the focus is. But the problem is I can get focus on list row if I add

View getting hang up due to multiple views inside row file, to get click You have to add one more property to your main layout of row xml.

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants`

> But when I write above property then I'm not able to focus ImageButton which is in my row file.

I just tried one way to acheive to get foucus on `ImageButton` as well as on `listview`.

*To get focus on ImageButton:*

1. Create one selector file.
2. Applied on Imagebutton.
3. Added `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to ImageButton.

*To get focus on Listview:*

1. Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants` to main-layout within row xml.

Now when you click on your ImageButton it will focus with your desire color even it will focus on listview click too.

*Selecotor.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Tested in S3 emulator, works well.

Comment: I did all the above things but its not working in nexus 7 emulator as well as in TV. I think its because there is no touch screen for TV so android:focusableInTouchMode="true" is not working

Comment: Is focus going to list row and button...?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem before. I solved my problem with adding (to the layout in xml)

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

So my problem was resolved.

Note: Adding only android:focusableInTouchMode="true" doesn't work, You must have to make the layout clickable true, after focusableInTouchMode true.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in listView but I found the solution,simply use imageView instead of image button, then row will be clickable and focusable as well.
NOTE: when ever we use button or imagebutton in listView the row of the list view gets disable to prevent this from happening use view or imageview instead.

Hope so this will help you.

Comment: I couldn't get the ImageButton to work even with all the suggested comments, but this worked.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code to the parent layout of custom row,

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and add below code to any button or ImageButton in that layout

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

or

```
setFocusable(false);
```

On both your items  (ImageButton and TextView) ?

Comment: Thanks for your time but if user can't focus then with remote control user won't know if he is on the correct ImageButton...

Answer (score 0):

List view items not not focusable with Android Tv Remote.
This is how I solved it.

If you are using List View or Recycler View.
In OnBindView method.
root layout of single item of listview/reyclerview

```
rootLayout.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if(b){  
                  rootLayout.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grey));
                }else { 
                 rootLayout.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
                }
            }
        });
```