# Can not select item in Listview in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to print a few items in a listview which is in a Fragment.
The problem I have encountered is that I can not click, select, an item in my list. The all list is grey. I can not do anything with it, except tick the checkbox in the items. I can scroll up and down but no click on a row.

This is my fragment class :

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment
{
ArrayList<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.backup, container, false);

    ListAdapter boxAdapter;
    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), elements);
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    // I have no idea here on what to do
    lvMain.setClickable(true);
    lvMain.setChoiceMode(2);
    lvMain.setFocusable(true);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
    lvMain.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    lvMain.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {

        }

      });
    return rootView;
}
```

My List Adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  Context ctx;
  LayoutInflater lInflater;
  ArrayList<Element> objects;

  ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Element> ele) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = ele;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Element p = getElement(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.size)).setText(p.getSize().toString());
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.getImage());

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
        cb.setTag(position);
        cb.setChecked(p.isBox());


        return view;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you mean to say  you can check checkbox in a listview but not click the row of the lisview?

Comment: Maybe it's because your `setOnItemClickListener` is undefined...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't replied to what i asked then the only reason i can think of is that either you have set the width of `checkbox` as `match_parent` or `fill_parent` and that `checkbox` is getting all the focus.

Please set the width of `checkbox` to be `wrap_content` and then set it non-focusable i.e. not taking all the focus of it's `parent`, `listview`, and allowing it focus if it can.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then please post your `xml` to determine what the actual problem is.

Comment: That was exactly this, thanks a lot !! A little thing I've lost so much hour on it... thank you !

Comment: @user3091982 you are welcome. In future keep in mind that you are placing a view (checkbox) over another view (listview) thus checkbox will take all the press events. By using setFocusable="false" we are giving chance to other view to be able to access any touch event. Some FYI for you, Whenever a answer helps you please upvote it, to encourage the answer givers. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem probably is that you have checkbox inside list item because checkbox is focusable.

Try look at this answer [Android custom ListView with ImageButton is not getting focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249632/android-custom-listview-with-imagebutton-is-not-getting-focus)