# can we have both of Button and onItemClick listener in ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, onitemselectedlistener

I have `Button` in each row of `ListView` and `onClickListener` for `Button`. I want to add `onItemSelectListener` to my `ListView` too. Is it possible? If  yes how can I do that?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @max: it's suppose to be possible.look on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70   . watch from minute 24

Comment: Hi after some research on internet i found [this good example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249632/android-custom-listview-with-imagebutton-is-not-getting-focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible ...

While creating custom view adapter for listview, u have to add onclicklistener on button 
and u can also need to add onItemSelectListener on Listview.
It would work.

use listview code as

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
      listView .setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter (this,userIDArr));


      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

              Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                        "Item in position " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        });
```

and create adapter like

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Activity context;
    public CustomListAdapter (Activity context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, names);
        this.context = context;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {

        public TextView Description;
        public Button  UploadBtn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.Description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.User_status);
            holder.UploadBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.uploadbutton);
            holder.UploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

                    public void onClick(View v) {  
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this," Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }   
                }); 
                rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.Description.setText("U r in middle");
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Now to handle click inside a list item use the below code

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

set these lines while creating Button tag

It would work ...
Please let me know your feedback..

Comment: @Simple Plan .. Plz look at my updated answer.. and let me kw if it worked for u or not

Comment: @NS great. +1 up from me.

Comment: thanks for your attention.where i should use this code android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"     in my singlelistitem or in listview?

Comment: where u have created ur layout for custom view. use these lines inside button tag on which u wanna act on click

Comment: in ur singlelistitem.. @max plz update me ur feedback

Comment: @NehaShukla sorry for late. i actually have customadapter for listview and image button inested of button. i try my custmadapter which extend baseadapter  and  use this android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" codes for my goal and thats not work. its different if i use baseadapter or Stringadapter in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Ya its possible!!!

you can use custom view in android or custom list view in android