# How and where to set an OnClickListener listener for two RecyclerView instances

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have two `RecyclerView` in my `Activity`. I set an `OnClickListener` for one of them and implement the `onItemClick` method.

If I want to set `OnClickListener` and implement `onItemClick` for the second `RecyclerView`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623060/can-we-have-both-of-button-and-onitemclick-listener-in-listview-in-android

Comment: Firstly, Why do anyone needs to click Recyclerview, Recyclerview item such as button or text should be clickable. Secondly, Please give some more details and code regarding your question.

Comment: Can you set onClickListner by RecyclerAdapter

Comment: The recommended way to add listeners to a RecyclerView is to make the ViewHolder implement the listener and then register the listener on the View passed to the ViewHolder constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set click listner on both of the `RecyclerView` by `RecyclerviewAdapter` class.

Inside `onBindViewHolder()` of Adapter Class. (Same code for both of the `RecyclerView` Adapter class)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    LoadDataResult listPotn = list.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Call intent or call method of Activity from here.

            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , Excercise.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Or,

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView product_name;

ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    product_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemPosition + ":" + String.valueOf(product_name.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: @MostafaPirhayati I wouldn't recommend this approach as it requires creating a new listener instance which can be avoided. Also, the adapter should ideally not know about what a `ViewHolder` does when it is clicked. The `Adapter` should only be responsible for supplying `ViewHolder` instances and binding data into them. See my answer for an approach that uses better design principles.

Comment: @CKing yours answer is also good way to achieve clicklistner but mine answer is also correct and easy way .

Comment: @AbhisekKumar It is leaky design if the adapter has to know about how clicks are handled. That is not what an `Adapter` is for. Separation of concerns is an important design principle and violating it leads to classes doing things they shouldn't be doing. Case in point is the above answer. The purpose of `onBindViewHolder` is to bind data to a view. There is no reason why it should have anything remotely to do with setting up a listener. There is always going to be more than one way to achieve something, one should make sure they chose an approach that follows good design principles.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to add listeners to a `RecyclerView` is to make the `ViewHolder` implement the listener and then register the listener on the `View` that is passed to the `ViewHolder` constructor. Example :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>    

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something on click using the position
             int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
       }
   }  
}
```

If you have two RecyclerView classes, you need to set the listener in the second `ViewHolder` implementation in a similar fashion.

**Note :** While there are multiple ways in which one can register a listener for a `RecyclerView`, the above approach defines the `ViewHolder` implementaion as an inner class in the adapter class and also ensures that only classes that need to know about clicks contain the code for handling them.