# Listview click listener not responding

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and want to perform clickable event on it. I did it before. but now its not working. I have added my XML as well. I just need to move from one actvity to other on click in list view.

```
      CustomFinalSubmit_ItemDetail item = new  CustomFinalSubmit_ItemDetail(Final_Submit.this , R.layout.customview_finalsubmit_itemdetails, itemInfo);
    itemList.setAdapter(item);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            FinalSubmitItem pos = itemInfo.get(position);
            String itemType = pos.getItemType();
            String itemCountry = pos.getItemCountry();
            String itemSerial = pos.getItemNo();
            pos.setChecked(true);

            Intent inn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FinalSubmitDetails.class);
            inn.putExtra("itemType", itemType);
            inn.putExtra("itemCountry", itemCountry);
            inn.putExtra("itemSerial", itemSerial);
            startActivity(inn);
        }

    });
```

Here is my main Xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/green">  
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#0B3B0B">
<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/CustomerDetailList"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/yellow"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/Itemtype"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:text="Item Type"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtcountry"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:text="Country"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemNumber"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:text="Item No."/>
     <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/itemChck"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>  
        </LinearLayout>  
 <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="@color/white"/> 
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemList"
    android:background="#088A08"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you have any `focusable` widget on list Item (like imageButton , button )?

Comment: Do you happen to have added a Button or similar in the layout of the items?

Comment: what do you mean by "now its not working",post your logcat?

Comment: @GiruBhai On click it must move to another activity..its not doing this.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan..I have a checkbox in listview

Comment: @cYrixmorten..I have a checkbox in listview

Comment: you can use `view.setOnClickListener()` on `getView()` method

Comment: XML looks weird to me, is the LinearLayout for item not suppose to be in a seperate file, being inflated into the List? Looks like you have the layout of an item below the list, and if so, no wonder the list does not respond to clicks, if it is empty.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I think you are right. user3740085 should read some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) of `ListView` before using it.

Comment: ok..guys..I'll read them..thanks for answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                     your code
                }});
```

Just add this much code to my customview

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem after adding a ToggleButton to my list items. The solution for me was to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the layout of the item.

Here is the whole XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/watch_roadName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Addresse"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/watch_button_arrived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/watch_roadName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textOn="@string/arrived"
        android:textOff="@string/arrived"
        android:text="@string/arrived" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Similar answers to the same issue can be found here:

[How to fire onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

and here

[Android custom ListView with ImageButton is not getting focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249632/android-custom-listview-with-imagebutton-is-not-getting-focus)

Comment: May I have some explanation about it..and if you could please let me know how to make checkbox checked on click in listview

Comment: Sorry, worked for me. Unfortunately I cannot remember where I found the solution and hence the full explanation but it ultimately prevents the Button from blocking focus from the rest of the list item.

Answer (score 0):

in the widgets(Textview or button whatever it is) of your inflator layout just add:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and in parent layout of your inflator  add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```